# APK built by Unity won't install - INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES - APK Signature Scheme v2: SHA-256 digest of contents did not verify

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I kept encountering INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES whenever I install games that I built with Unity, versions I've tried are 2019.4.30f1, 2019.4.40f1, and 2021.3.33f1

I've looked on the internet and attempted these:

- Reimport project
- Changing launcher gradle template to have `signingConfig signingConfigs.debug`
- Changing build settings

  - Scripting Backend: IL2CPP to Mono or vice versa
  - Checked ARMv7 and ARM64
  - Write Permission (External to Internal and vice versa)
  - Install Location (Tried every option and rebuilding them)
  - Using custom keystores and debug keystores
- Changing SDK path to the one from Android Studio

I basically asked someone else in my team to build it for me and it works fine for them with the configurations I chose, is there anything I can do to fix this issue?

Here's some of the error message when I try to install through adb

````
adb: failed to install <APK_FILEPATH>: Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES: Failed to collect certificates from /data/app/vmdl500565485.tmp/base.apk using APK Signature Scheme v2: SHA-256 digest of contents did not verify]
]
stdout[
Performing Streamed Install
]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <58f97c829555465ba5d28d3aa0de2614>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <58f97c829555465ba5d28d3aa0de2614>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <58f97c829555465ba5d28d3aa0de2614>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.ADB.RunInternal (System.String[] command, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <58f97c829555465ba5d28d3aa0de2614>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.ADB.Run (System.String[] command, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <58f97c829555465ba5d28d3aa0de2614>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidDevice.Exec (System.String[] command, System.String errorMsg) (at <58f97c829555465ba5d28d3aa0de2614>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidDevice.Install (System.String apkfile) (at <58f97c829555465ba5d28d3aa0de2614>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidDeploymentTargetsExtension+<>c__DisplayClass19_0.<UploadAPK>b__0 () (at <58f97c829555465ba5d28d3aa0de2614>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidDeploymentTargetsExtension.UploadAPK (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildProperties buildProperties, UnityEditor.Android.AndroidDevice device, UnityEditor.Android.AndroidDeploymentTargetsExtension+LaunchProgressTaskManager taskManager) (at <58f97c829555465ba5d28d3aa0de2614>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidDeploymentTargetsExtension+<>c__DisplayClass15_1.<LaunchBuildOnTarget>b__3 () (at <58f97c829555465ba5d28d3aa0de2614>:0)
UnityEditor.ProgressTaskManager.Run () (at <06837d428b6d46f581d93f9597703696>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidDeploymentTargetsExtension.LaunchBuildOnTarget (UnityEditor.DeploymentTargets.IDeploymentTargetsMainThreadContext context, UnityEditor.BuildProperties buildProperties, UnityEditor.DeploymentTargets.DeploymentTargetId targetId, UnityEditor.ProgressHandler progressHandler) (at <58f97c829555465ba5d28d3aa0de2614>:0)
UnityEditor.DeploymentTargets.DeploymentTargetManager.LaunchBuildOnTarget (UnityEditor.BuildProperties buildProperties, UnityEditor.DeploymentTargets.DeploymentTargetId targetId, UnityEditor.ProgressHandler progressHandler) (at <06837d428b6d46f581d93f9597703696>:0)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer+<>c__DisplayClass22_1.<LaunchOnTargets>b__1 () (at <06837d428b6d46f581d93f9597703696>:0)
UnityEditor.ProgressTaskManager.Run () (at <06837d428b6d46f581d93f9597703696>:0)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.LaunchOnTargets (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget buildTarget, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport buildReport, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] launchTargets) (at <06837d428b6d46f581d93f9597703696>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.Launch (UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <58f97c829555465ba5d28d3aa0de2614>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.LaunchPlayer (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildLaunchPlayerArgs args) (at <58f97c829555465ba5d28d3aa0de2614>:0)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Launch (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget buildTarget, System.String path, System.String productName, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport buildReport) (at <06837d428b6d46f581d93f9597703696>:0)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)```
````